# What happens when a question is edited while under review for Close Votes?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, review-queues, edits, vote-to-close

I recently came across a question that, in its original state, was lacking an MCVE. An initial "needs MCVE" close vote was cast, and the question was queued for review. Shortly after, the asker edited their question to include a full MCVE.

However, over the next 8 hours or so *after* the full MCVE had been introduced, the question continued receiving "needs MCVE" close votes, eventually getting closed. I had to reopen it myself.

Looking at the review task now, I see the question in its edited state. Is there a bug in review causing the question to appear in its original state before the review task is completed, which would explain the additional close votes (and the Close decisions on the review task)? Note that I did not examine the review task until after the question was closed and the review task completed.

Comment: Your assumption that people in the review queue wouldn't vote to close it after it's been edited is nice, but rather naive in my experiences.

Comment: @Servy: "Assume good faith", they said :(

Comment: I'm not assuming malice, I'm assuming laziness/incompetence.

Comment: `Shortly after, the asker edited their question to include a full MCVE.` That one question where the OP responded to feedback? I had heard legends.

Comment: "full MCVE" may still deserve CV if "minimal" part is completely ignored - I've seen enough cases where edit just dumps whole project with random parts commented, empty functions and like. I would not blame reviewers if  "*minimal* sample" does not fit on the page.

Comment: @BoltClock Part of why the close vote queue is actually tosh. Many people don't bother checking other then is it an audit or not and other then that just VTC as fast as they can using the same reasons that the other voters before them used.

Comment: related: [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just tested this on https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11389027 (edited outside of the queue, then reloaded the review task):

[image]

The edited version is shown. I don't see any reason it would behave differently if the OP edited.

I suspect people are just reviewing too fast, or don't know what they're doing. Probably both.

Comment: Good to know the system is working as intended at least.

Comment: Are these `[1]` and `[2]` from some userscript which adds keyboard shortcuts for these buttons? If yes could you give a link?

Comment: @Gothdo Yep, https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/CloseVoteShortcuts.user.js